# Writing from a list to a Word document

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-docx

I have written code (shown below) that reads in a word document, and writes each "run" with formatting into a list.  Thus creating a list of formatted runs, so that I may use some or all at a later time.  Next, I have written code to write said runs from said list to a new document.  The issue is I keep getting an error stating " "Run" object is not iterable".  I don't know if the issue is that writing all of the paragraph information to a list that can be recalled can not be done this way, or if I am trying to write it to the document the wrong way.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from docx import Document  # Invokes Document command from docx


def get_para_data(output_doc_name, paragraph):
    """
    Write the run to the new file and then set its font, bold, alignment, color etc. data.
    """
    output_run = []
    output_para = output_doc_name.add_paragraph()
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        if paragraph:
            output_run = output_para.add_run(run.text)
            # Run's bold data
            output_run.bold = run.bold
            # Run's italic data
            output_run.italic = run.italic
            # Run's underline data
            output_run.underline = run.underline
            # Run's color data
            output_run.font.color.rgb = run.font.color.rgb
            # Run's font data
            output_run.style.name = run.style.name
            # Paragraph's alignment data
            output_para.paragraph_format.alignment = paragraph.paragraph_format.alignment
        else:
            output_run = []
    return output_run

# IMPORT WORD DOCUMENT
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
# returns the file path as variable for future use.
doc_path = askopenfilename(title="Choose Word File")
# Imports Word Document to Modify.
document = Document(doc_path)
# Number of paragraphs in document.
t = len(document.paragraphs)
# Preallocation of list.
output_paragraph = [None]*t
result = Document()
# Begin loop to create list of paragraph data using function created above.
i = 0
for para in document.paragraphs:
    output_paragraph[i] = get_para_data(result, document.paragraphs[i])

# Write desired portion of document into a new document.
document_new = Document()
new_line = []
a = 0
for out in output_paragraph:
# Check to Verify it is not a blank line/return.
    if output_paragraph:
        new_line[a] = document_new.add_paragraph(output_paragraph[a])
        a += 1
# if it is a blank line/return write blank line return.
    else:
        document_new.add_paragraph(text='\\r', style=None)
        a += 1
```

My expected results were that the text in the new document was the same as in the previous document, but in an order i choose.  Similar to a copy and paste, but I wanted the ability to choose which portions I "pasted" and when.

Comment: Please provide the proper formatting (indents). This is very important in python. Or is this actually how it is indented?

Comment: You have not defined paragraph before you try to iterate through paragraph.runs

Comment: The function at the top runs great.  I think the problems is in the last for loop with the first if statement.  The former is there to give the problem some background, and understanding.  It doesn't like that I am trying to use a paragraph stored in a list, or I have coded it incorrectly to write the list paragraph to the new document.